# How do I access the value of a map inside a yaml file for PyYAML?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

Say I have a YAML file that looks like this:

```
food:
  fruits: 
    round: apple
    big: watermelon
  grain: wheat
  vegetable: cabbage
```

I want to be able to write the equivalent of the python code `tasty = food['fruits']['round']` (which would resolve to apple) inside the YAML document.

I can get as far as referencing one variable hence I can do

```
food: &FOOD
  fruits: 
    round: apple
    big: watermelon
  grain: wheat
  vegetable: cabbage
```

and then reference the entire map, like

```
something: *FOOD
```

but how do I lookup a value inside a map of maps within the YAML itself?

Comment: There is nothing in the spec supporting elements of a sequence or values of a mapping using its key. You can approach what you want by using tags and appropriate Python objects, but it looks relatively ugly. If you want to be able to specify `something: $FOOD.fruits.big`, that is easily done by postprocessing the loaded data. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: yes, ideally I would like it all to be self contained as it would be more elegant but if post-processing is unavoidable and the spec says nothing about a method then I'm fine with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an anchor for a single value:

```
import yaml


def main():
    yf = """
    food:
      fruits: 
        round: &FOOD apple
        big: watermelon
      grain: wheat
      vegetable: cabbage
    something: *FOOD
    """

    print(yaml.load(yf))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

prints:
{'food': {'vegetable': 'cabbage', 'grain': 'wheat', 'fruits':
{'big': 'watermelon', 'round': 'apple'}}, 'something': 'apple'}

Comment: No I don't mean loading it into python. I mean self referencing within the yaml itself

Comment: @user3325789: That's what I did - See the `&FOOD`, and `*FOOD` strings.

Comment: But that requires an explicit anchor to the submap. Is there no way to reference the values by setting the anchor to the outer map and then selecting down the KV tree as we would in python?

Comment: @user3325789:  You're welcome to read the [spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), but it looks like it's all or nothing - there is no syntax to only reference part of an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
food: &FOOD
  fruits:
    round: apple
    big: watermelon
  grain: [wheat, barley, spelt]
  vegetable: cabbage
something: $FOOD.fruits.big
otherthing: $.food.grain.2   # 2 -> third element
"""

def resolve(data, sep='.', initial='$'):
    """walk over tree and resolve strings that start with $
       $XYZ.abc -> resolve starting at anchor XYZ
       $.abc -> resolve starting at toplevel
    """
    def get_anchors(d, anchors):
        if isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
            if d.yaml_anchor() is not None:
                anchors[d.anchor.value] = d
            for k in d:
                get_anchors(d[k], anchors)
        elif isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq):
            if d.yaml_anchor() is not None:
                anchors[d.anchor.value] = d
            for e in d:
                get_anchors(e, anchors)

    def resolvex(data, d, anchors, sep, initial):
        if isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
            for k in d:
                upd, val = resolvex(data, d[k], anchors, sep, initial)
                if upd:
                    d[k] = val
            return False, None
        elif isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq):
            for idx, e in enumerate(d):
                upd, val = resolvex(data, e, anchors, sep, initial)
                if upd:
                    d[idx] = val
            return False, None
        if isinstance(d, str) and d and d[0] == initial:
            path = d[1:].split(sep)
            dx = data if path[0] == '' else anchors.get(path[0])
            while len(path) > 1:
                path = path[1:]
                if isinstance(dx, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq):
                    dx = dx[int(path[0])]
                else:
                    dx = dx[path[0]]
            return True, dx
        return False, None

    anchors = {}
    get_anchors(data, anchors=anchors)
    resolvex(data, data, anchors, sep, initial)

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
resolve(data)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

with output:

```
food:
  fruits:
    round: apple
    big: watermelon
  grain: [wheat, barley, spelt]
  vegetable: cabbage
something: watermelon
otherthing: spelt            # 2 -> third element
```

Please note that you cannot do the above with PyYAML as it doesn't preserve the anchor names, you'll have to use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).